# Cocoa replaceSubview for nib loaded from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nib

I've got a `.storyboard` that loads a `.nib` into it's view controller using:

```
NSViewController* vc = [[otherView alloc] initWithNibName:@"otherView" bundle:nil];
[[[self window] contentView] addSubView:[vc view]];
```

This works fine for loading in the initial NSView, however, the `.nib` contains several other views I would like to be able to replace with a different view when a button is clicked.

How do I specify which view in the `.nib` I would like to replace with another?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect other view as outlet to the NSViewController and you can call replace.